Reducing Time Complexity for Barycentric Subdivision
During my research, I tried to replicate a graph found in this article, but my computer has not granted me the amount of iterations I am looking for (7+). Now, I am a very inexperienced programmer, but I don't see how to optimize the time complexity for my code, which I figure it O($6^n$) since barycentric subdivision subdivides a triangle into 6, and those 6 into 36, and so on. Here's my code if anyone would give it a shot and shed some advice for me going forward:
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

def conventional_form(a, b, c):

   # Find longest side and scale to length 1
   side1 = np.abs(a - b)
   side2 = np.abs(b - c)
   side3 = np.abs(c - a)

   if side1 >= side2 and side1 >= side3:
      longest_side = side1
      v1, v2, v3 = a, b, c
   elif side2 >= side1 and side2 >= side3:
      longest_side = side2
      v1, v2, v3 = b, c, a
   else:
      longest_side = side3
      v1, v2, v3 = c, a, b

   scaling_factor = 1 / longest_side
   scaled_v1 = v1 * scaling_factor
   scaled_v2 = v2 * scaling_factor
   scaled_v3 = v3 * scaling_factor

   # Rotating scaled_vertices so the longest side is horizontal and the other vertex is above the horizontal line
   theta = np.angle(v2 - v1)
   rotation_factor = np.exp(-1j * theta)

   rotated_v1 = scaled_v1 * rotation_factor
   rotated_v2 = scaled_v2 * rotation_factor
   rotated_v3 = scaled_v3 * rotation_factor

   if rotated_v3.imag < rotated_v1.imag:
      rotated_v3 = complex(rotated_v3.real, 2 * rotated_v1.imag - rotated_v3.imag)

   # Translate rotated_vertices so v1 = 0 and v2 = 0 + 1j
   translation = -rotated_v1

   a_new = rotated_v1 + translation
   b_new = rotated_v2 + translation
   c_new = rotated_v3 + translation

   # Moving top vertex to left-side if needed
   if c_new.real >= 0.50:
      c_new = complex(1 - c_new.real, c_new.imag)

   return a_new, b_new, c_new

def plot_point(point, color='black', markersize=2):
   plt.scatter(point.real, point.imag, color=color, s=markersize)

def barycentric_subdivision(a, b, c, subdivisions):
   if subdivisions == 0:
      return

   # Transform the vertices to the conventional form
   a_new, b_new, c_new = conventional_form(a, b, c)

   # Plot the c_new vertex
   plot_point(c_new)

   # Define the 6 new triangles
   ab_mid = (a + b) / 2
   bc_mid = (b + c) / 2
   ca_mid = (c + a) / 2
   centroid = (a + b + c) / 3

   triangles = [
      (a, ab_mid, centroid),
      (ab_mid, b, centroid),
      (b, bc_mid, centroid),
      (bc_mid, c, centroid),
      (c, ca_mid, centroid),
      (ca_mid, a, centroid)
   ]

   # Recursively apply barycentric subdivision to each new triangle
   for tri in triangles:
      barycentric_subdivision(*tri, subdivisions - 1)

def calculate_plotted_points(subdivisions):
   return 1 + 6 ** (subdivisions - 1)

# Input
a = complex(1, 1.5)
b = complex(1.5, 2.5)
c = complex(0.5, 2.5)
subdivisions = 7

plt.figure()
barycentric_subdivision(a, b, c, subdivisions)
plt.xlim(0, 1)
plt.ylim(0, 1)
num_plotted_points = calculate_plotted_points(subdivisions)
plt.title(f"Subdivisions: {subdivisions}\nPlotted Points: {num_plotted_points}")

plt.show()


My conventional_form function is based off the excerpt from the article saying

Given a triangle, first scale it so that its longest side has length one. Then rotate it so its longest side is horizontal. Rotate it again (by 180$^\circ$) if necessary so the triangle is on top of its longest side. Flip it around a vertical axis, if necessary, so that its shortest side is at the left. The triangle we are now looking at is very special: its bottom side is a horizontal segment of length 1 (because we have scaled it suitably); its top vertex lies at distance at most one from its right hand vertex (because the right side is at most as long as the bottom); and the top vertex lies to the left of the center of the bottom (because of our convention regarding mirror images). If we are given a coordinate system, we may even place the bottom to be the segment from (0, 0) to (1,0).

Using 6 subdivisions, this program takes maybe 20 seconds, but 7 has never finished. Thank you for whoever can help.

I would imagine what is taking the time is the translation to your "conventional form". Can you try computing all the triangles first, then vectorizing (using numpy operations on whole arrays) to get the single point from each that you want to plot. BTW, you might get more answers if you explained what you were trying to do in the question than requiring people to read and digest quite a long article.

Thank you for the suggestion, worked like a charm!
